# How should I test that an observable throws an error?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, error-handling, jasmine, observable

How should I test that an observable throws an error?

```
const target = () => 
  Observable.of(1)
    .map(() => Observable.throw('an error'));
```

I have tried the following ways to check for the error with Jasmine:

```
expect(target().subscribe(x => x)).toThrow();

let failingFunction = () => target;
expect(() => failingFunction).toThrow();

target.subscribe(() => null, err => expect(err).toBeDefined());
```

Comment: Can't you simply use the observable API to catch the error, and then pass or fail the test on the basis of this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this?

```
it('should throw an error', (done) => {
  target()
    .next(fail)
    .catch((err) => {
      expect(err).toBe('an error');
      done();
    });
});
```